# WPF MVVM Validation on passthrough property on VM

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I am trying to use IDataErrorInfo for validation in WPF+MVVM. I followed MSDN article of how to implement it. The question is that what do I do with the pass through property on the VM?

For example,

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    protected string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if (propertyName == "Name")
            {
                if (Name == "ABC")
                {
                    result = "Name cannot be ABC";
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    A a = new A();

    public string ModelName
    {
        get
        {
            return a.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            a.Name = value;
            OnNameChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("ModelName");
        }
    }
}    

<TextBox Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Path=ModelName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

What do I have to do on the view model so that I don't have to re-validate the Name property again on the view model?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `"again"`? If you wanna validate one time, you can define a boolean property (ex: `hasNameValidated`).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to expose your whole Class A through your ViewModel.

This blog post (is not perfect but) show an easy way to do it: http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2012/7/2/simple-validation-in-wpf-mvvm-using-idataerrorinfo

Also you have an interesting discussion on How to display the error on this topic: [MVVM pattern, IDataErrorInfo and Binding to display error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123062/mvvm-pattern-idataerrorinfo-and-binding-to-display-error)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, Class A is exposed through the ViewModel and IDataErrorInfo works perfectly when I bind directly to to the Model. However, from time to time, I need the pass-through properties on the View Model in order to do something on the View Model. When this happens, I have to implement IDataErrorInfo on View Model and do the same validation again as I did on the Model. Is there anyway to avoid doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Validation occurs on the class that has the binding set. In your case it is the `ViewModel`. If you have to have pass through properties then just implement the `IDataErrorInfo` on the `ViewModel` and have that pass through also

//ViewModel

```
public string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        if (propertyName == "ModelName")
        {
            return a["Name"];
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I do not know of a way around not having the `IDataErrorInfo` on the `ViewModel` in your case

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of this way. The way I am doing it now is to not use the pass-through property on the View Model. Instead, I get View Model to listen to the propertychanged event from the Model and do stuff if the changes comes from the properties I care. Is there any draw back that would make me not going this route?